# Getting the exact format for DateTime from an XML file

Tags: c#

In my XML I have a date value as shown below:

```
[CDATA[07/07/1980]]
```

I do the following to retrieve the date:

```
public static DateTime? GetDateTimeValue(string dateTimeString)
    {
        DateTime i;
        if ((dataTimeString != null) && (dataTimeString.Value.Trim() != ""))
            if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out i))
                return i;

        return null;         
    }
```

The value I get is `07/07/1980 12:00:00 AM`.

I can do the following:

```
DatdTime.TryParse(dateTimeString.ToShortDateString())
```

But I don't want to manipulate the data in any way. I want to get the date as is.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `(dataTimeString != null) && (dataTimeString.Trim() != "")` just `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateTimeString)`

Comment: `dateTimeString.ToShortDateString`? A string is not a `DateTime`.  String also has no `Value` property(`dataTimeString.Value.Trim`). Please provide compiling code.

Comment: That whole thing is not needed when doing tryparse

Comment: Use a custom datetime format without any time specification.

Comment: the value you get is the exact datetime, what is the problem?  also, curly braces are free, might as well use them.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I am sorry it is NOT dateTimeString.ToshortDateString() it is i.ToshortDateString()

Comment: the value I get is the exact datetime. but the problem is 12:00:00 AM is not in the data. eg: a birth date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I use, but I do not use a nullable `DateTime`.

```
private static DateTime nodate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
public static DateTime NODATE { get { return nodate; } }

public static DateTime GetDate(object obj) {
  if ((obj != null) && (obj != DBNull.Value)) { // Databases return DBNull.Value
    try {
      return Convert.ToDateTime(obj);
    } catch (Exception) { }
    try {
      return DateTime.Parse(obj.ToString());
    } catch (Exception) { }
  }
  return NODATE;
}
```

I can't always use `TryParse` because a lot of my code has to be Compact Framework safe.

If anything goes wrong, I will see my NODATE value (January 1, 1900) in my date fields. It is pretty safe to guess that most of my database programs have no date if they try to display something indicating they were input on January 1st of 1900. After all: Everyone has New Year's off, right? :)

Comment: is DateTime.MinValue not available to the Compact Framework?  that would save you the trouble of defining NODATE

Comment: Looks like `DateTime.MinValue` is DateTime(0001, 1, 1). A lot of stuff may be able to use that. I'll have to check if SQLite can go that low.

Comment: there is also SqlDateTime.MinValue & SqlDateTime.MaxValue which work with SQL server, dunno about sqlite